# Unrecognized selector when swipe

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, unrecognized-selector

I need to catch swipe-action only on special area. But debugger tells `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
          initWithTarget:self.viewName action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
}

-(void)didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe{
   NSLog(@"swiped left");
}
```

whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the target to be `self` not `self.imageName`.

---

**Edit** In response to your comments.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.viewName addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

You want your `target` to be the place where the method lives. In this case that should be `self`. You want to add your gesture recognizer to the view that is supposed to be touched, `self.viewName`.

Comment: well, it really works, but with all screen. And how can I cath this gesture only when it starts in special area?

Comment: Not even so. I need that swipe will not work anywhere except smal area :)

Comment: If it needs to be in a certain area you should not add the gesture recognizer to the entire `self.view`. Try adding it to a subview that's in the correct spot for where you want the user to swipe.

Comment: same problem when I create UIView viewName. I just dont know what to write in **initWithTarget**

Comment: I edited my response above. Let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Answer (score 6):

Your gesture recognizer has an argument, so that should be `@selector(didSwipe:)` (Note the colon).